# SAPUI5 I can't load the table from the Rest Service

Tags: rest, sapui5, loaddata

I'm in trouble. I can load my table from the same local Json, however, I can not load a table when I read the Rest. Both are returning the Json because I tested. 
Would this error be related to Syncronous and Asyncronous?

This is the code which is not working

```
        var oModelGET = new JSONModel();
        var urlGET = 'http://localhost/Compliance/api/RestServiceImpl.svc/getTFCompanyList';
        var parametersGET = {};

        var headersGET = {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "X-Invoiceware-Token": oModelPOST.getProperty("/Token"),
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        };
        oModelGET.loadData(urlGET, parametersGET, false, "GET", false, "false", headersGET);
        this.setModel(oModelGET, "products");
```

---

This code is working:

```
        // set invoice model - local
        var oInvoiceModel = new JSONModel()
        var invoiceLocal = "/test/localService/mockdata/Products.json";
        var sNamespace = "sap.ui.compliance";

        oInvoiceModel.loadData(jQuery.sap.getModulePath(sNamespace, invoiceLocal));
        this.setModel(oInvoiceModel, "products");
```

---

This is my xml

```
<core:View
   controllerName="controller.security.Companies"
    xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form"
xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
xmlns="sap.m">
  <Page title="{i18n>companiesViewTitle}">
   <content>
   <Table busyIndicatorDelay="{worklistView>/tableBusyDelay}"
         class="sapUiResponsiveMargin"
         growing="true"
         growingScrollToLoad="true"
               id="tableCompanies"
         items="{ path: 'products>/Products', sorter: { path: 'products>/Name', descending: false } }"
         noDataText="{worklistView>/tableNoDataText}"
                 updateFinished="onUpdateFinished" width="auto">
    <headerToolbar>
      <Toolbar>
        <Title id="tableCompanyHeader" text="Companies (n)"/>
        <ToolbarSpacer/>
        <SearchField id="searchField" search="onSearch" tooltip="Search" width="auto"></SearchField>
        <Button type="Default" icon="sap-icon://add" press="handleNewCompanypress"/>
      </Toolbar>
    </headerToolbar>
    <columns>
      <Column id="companyCol" minScreenWidth="Small" demandPopin="true">
        <Text text="Company" />
      </Column>
      <Column id="nameCol" minScreenWidth="Small" demandPopin="true">
        <Text text="Name" />
      </Column>
    </columns>
    <items>
      <ColumnListItem press="handleListItempress" type="Navigation">
        <cells>
          <ObjectIdentifier
            title="{products>Name}"/>
          <Text
            text="{products>SearchCode}" />
        </cells>
      </ColumnListItem>
    </items>
  </Table>
  </content>
  <footer>
  <OverflowToolbar id="otbFooter">
  </OverflowToolbar>
  </footer>
  </Page>
  </core:View>
```

Thank you

Comment: do you see any errors in console? How is the response looking like?

Comment: What does the view has to do with that problem? why you show us this XML?

Comment: Is your Rest Service a OData service? What is the call you tested it?